# Sybase ORDER BY slow request

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, sap-ase

Can't imagine what to do here. My query is:

```
SELECT
    ACCOUNT.ID,
    ACCOUNT.NAME,
    SUPPLIERACCOUNT.NAME,
    HEADER.CURRENCY,
    HEADER.DDATE,
    HEADER.RECIPIENTACCOUNTNUMBER,
    HEADER.REQUESTID,
    HEADER.PRINCIPALAMOUNT,
    LINEITEM.HEADERID,
    LINEITEM.DATE
FROM
    ACCOUNT
         JOIN HEADER ON ACCOUNT.ID = HEADER.ISSUERACCOUNTNUMBER
         JOIN ACCOUNT AS SUPPLIERACCOUNT ON HEADER.RECIPIENTACCOUNTNUMBER = SUPPLIERACCOUNT.ID
         JOIN LINEITEM ON HEADER.HEADERID = LINEITEM.HEADERID
WHERE ACCOUNT.BPID = 7222222
  AND LINEITEM.LTYPE = 'P'
  AND HEADER.POSTINGDATE >= ACCOUNT.CREATIONDATE
  and ACCOUNT.ID IN (1111111,2222222 ...)
  and HEADER.RECIPIENTACCOUNTNUMBER IN (3333333,6666666,9999999 ...)
  AND HEADER.POSTINGDATE >= '2018-11-17'
  AND HEADER.POSTINGDATE <= '2019-10-17'
ORDER BY LINEITEM.DATE, ACCOUNT.ID, LINEITEM.HEADERID
```

Without LINEITEM.DATE and LINEITEM.HEADERID in ORDER my query runs 2 sec, with them about 1 min. 
The result is about 200k rows. These columns in ORDER have indexes in tables.

Can someone, please, give me a hint, what I'm missing? 
Thank you.

Edit. 
Sybase version ASE 16.0.
With full ORDER and **set statistics time, io on**
I have this result:

```
[2019-10-20 22:05:17] [01000][3613] Parse and Compile Time 11.
[2019-10-20 22:05:17] Adaptive Server cpu time: 1100 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:05:17] [01000][3613] Parse and Compile Time 2.
[2019-10-20 22:05:17] Adaptive Server cpu time: 200 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3615] Table: Worktable1 scan count 1, logical reads: (regular=18136 apf=0 total=18136), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3615] Table: ACCOUNT scan count 214, logical reads: (regular=428 apf=0 total=428), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3615] Table: HEADER scan count 214, logical reads: (regular=14934 apf=0 total=14934), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3615] Table: LINEITEM scan count 199411, logical reads: (regular=420968 apf=0 total=420968), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3615] Table: ACCOUNT (SUPPLIERACCOUNT) scan count 501, logical reads: (regular=1002 apf=0 total=1002), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3631] Total actual I/O cost for this command: 874664.
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3614] Total writes for this command: 0

[2019-10-20 22:05:18] [01000][3612] Execution Time 566.
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] Adaptive Server cpu time: 56513 ms.  Adaptive Server elapsed time: 56790 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:05:18] 500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 58 s 825 ms (execution: 58 s 473 ms, fetching: 352 ms)
```

And with ORDER BY ACCOUNT.ID only i have:

```
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3613] Parse and Compile Time 11.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] Adaptive Server cpu time: 1100 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3613] Parse and Compile Time 2.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] Adaptive Server cpu time: 200 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: Worktable3 scan count 1, logical reads: (regular=2 apf=0 total=2), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: Worktable1 scan count 1, logical reads: (regular=2 apf=0 total=2), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: ACCOUNT scan count 1, logical reads: (regular=205 apf=0 total=205), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: HEADER scan count 2, logical reads: (regular=33 apf=0 total=33), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: LINEITEM scan count 501, logical reads: (regular=1142 apf=0 total=1142), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3615] Table: ACCOUNT (SUPPLIERACCOUNT) scan count 501, logical reads: (regular=1002 apf=0 total=1002), physical reads: (regular=0 apf=0 total=0), apf IOs used=0
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3631] Total actual I/O cost for this command: 4764.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3614] Total writes for this command: 0

[2019-10-20 22:15:22] [01000][3612] Execution Time 1.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] Adaptive Server cpu time: 105 ms.  Adaptive Server elapsed time: 106 ms.
[2019-10-20 22:15:22] 500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 2 s 163 ms (execution: 1 s 936 ms, fetching: 227 ms)
```

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? I'd recommend looking at the query plan of the 2 queries; also, if this is ASE, consider running both queries with 'set statistics time, io on' enabled and review the results; guesses ... different query plans ... nested loop join vs hash join ... index scanning to eliminate a sorting step ... out-of-date stats ... hard to say without a lot more details ...

Comment: Hello, markp. Sorry, I forgot to mention sybase version. Also update my question with statistics time and io. I guess my request stucks on LINEITEM table, not sure why, should I create index date_header on LINEITEM (DATE, HEADERID) ? Doesnt make sense to me, HEADERID is a PK and for DATE i have created index.

Comment: io stats are showing a much more expensive join order for the 1st/slower query: moderate worktable activity, excessive scans of ACCOUNT and HEADER, very high volume of scans of the LINEITEM table/index; you'll need to pull the query plans for both; the main question is going to be 'why' the different query plans ... which is going to require a good bit more info and analysis ... eg, any issue with datatype mismatches on the joins, any issues with out-of-date or skewed stats, etc.; do any of your ASE DBAs have P&T experience and if so, have you asked them for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only:

```
order by account.id
```

Sybase can clearly choose a query plan where it goes through the account table in `id` order and joins the rest of the rows and does the filtering.  This means that it can start returning results very quickly.  It is not clear if the 2 seconds is the time to the *first* result to to the *entire* result set.

With the more complex `order by`, Sybase has to generate the entire result set and then order it.  It cannot use indexes when the keys are mixed between tables.  Unless you are running on a wristwatch, it should not take a minute to sort 200k rows.  There are some caveats:

- If the rows are really wide, then sorting might take longer than expected.
- If the simpler `order by` *starts* returning results after 2 seconds but the entire result set takes much longer, then the comparison is not valid.